# Programa para quando uma declaração de estrutura ocorre em locais diferentes

Tags: c, socket, estrutura-de-dados

Segue o codigo-fonte...

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501

#include <stdio.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <winsock.h>
#include <windows.h>

WSADATA data;

struct addrinfo tips, *information;
void exaple_one(void);
void exaple_two(void);

void main(void) {

    printf("chamando o exemplo dois\n");
    exaple_two();
    printf("chamando o exemplo um = ERROR\n");
    exaple_one();
}

void exaple_one(void) {

    struct addrinfo tips, *information;

    WORD wRequestedVersion = MAKEWORD(1, 1);
    int iResult = WSAStartup(wRequestedVersion, &data);
    char localaddr[255];
    if(iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("Error...!");
    }

    getaddrinfo("www.netflix.com", NULL, &tips, &information);
    struct addrinfo *ponteiro;
    ponteiro = information;
    getnameinfo(ponteiro->ai_addr, ponteiro->ai_addrlen, localaddr, sizeof(localaddr), NULL, 0, NI_NUMERICHOST);
    printf("exaple one address = %s\n", localaddr);
}

void exaple_two(void) {

    WORD wRequestedVersion = MAKEWORD(1, 1);
    int iResult = WSAStartup(wRequestedVersion, &data);
    char localaddr[255];
    if(iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("Error...!");
    }

    getaddrinfo("www.netflix.com", NULL, &tips, &information);
    struct addrinfo *ponteiro;
    ponteiro = information;
    getnameinfo(ponteiro->ai_addr, ponteiro->ai_addrlen, localaddr, sizeof(localaddr), NULL, 0, NI_NUMERICHOST);
    printf("example two address = %s\n", localaddr);
}
```

se vocês compilar e executar o programa acima vera que a função example one para a execução do programa alguém poderia me explica por que isso ocorre ?

Comment: Qual o problema? Erro em tempo de execução do programa? Ou compilação ainda?

Answer (score 0):

O erro está acontecendo porque a estrutura `struct addrinfo tips` precisa ser inicializada antes de ser utilizada pela função *getaddrinfo()*, e os membros `ai_addrlen`, `ai_canonname`, `ai_addr` e `ai_next` dessa estrutura (*addrinfo*), **obrigatoriamente** devem ser inicializados com 0 ou *NULL*.

Abaixo, segue o código da função *exaple_one* corrigido:

```
void exaple_one(void) {

    struct addrinfo tips, *information;

    WORD wRequestedVersion = MAKEWORD(1, 1);
    int iResult = WSAStartup(wRequestedVersion, &data);
    char localaddr[255];
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("Error...!");
    }
    // *** Importante ***: "Zera" todos os componentes da estrutura
    ZeroMemory(&tips, sizeof(struct addrinfo)); 

    // "dicas" sobre o tipo de socket (não necessário)
    tips.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    tips.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    tips.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    getaddrinfo("www.netflix.com", NULL, &tips, &information);
    struct addrinfo *ponteiro;
    ponteiro = information;
    getnameinfo(ponteiro->ai_addr, ponteiro->ai_addrlen, localaddr, sizeof(localaddr), NULL, 0, NI_NUMERICHOST);
    printf("exaple one address = %s\n", localaddr);
}
```

Mais detalhes na documentação (em inglês): [getaddrinfo function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Muito bom vlw!!